# ONVIF IP camera discovery with c++

Tags: c++, ip-camera, discovery, onvif

I used the onvifcpplib library that you can find it in :
https://github.com/veyesys/onvifcpplib
I want to write the IP camera discovery with this library (it can find IP camera on network), but there isn't any documentation for this library.
anyone can help me?
thanks a lot

Comment: Worryingly, onvifclientremotediscovery.hpp is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onvifcpplib project on Github is apparently now called "[rapidonvif](https://github.com/linkingvision/rapidonvif)" and provided by linkvision on github as well.

I've never used it, but is seems to use the [gSOAP toolkit](https://www.genivia.com/products.html) to generate the web-services/soap stack used as backend for Onvif protocol.

If you just need to implement device discovery, you can develop your own code starting from the example provided by Genivia, the producer of the gSOAP toolkit, here:
https://www.genivia.com/examples/onvif/index.html

Pay attention that gSOAP is released under a dual license, GPLv2 that suits open-source projects, and commercial.
So if you are developing a commercial software, you may want to contact Genivia and buy a commercial license to use it (see also [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330174/what-license-do-i-need-to-use-gsoap-in-a-commercial-product))